# node.js - single process, or multiprocess?

Tags: node.js

[Here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3at5iEsHYKPXoJ%3awww.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-nodejs/+ibm+nodejs&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a&source=www.google.com) the author makes the follow statement:

> Instead of spawning a new OS thread for each connection (and allocating the accompanying memory with it), each connection CREATES A PROCESS, which doesn't require the memory block to go with it.

Does Node really spawn a process per request?! That's not how I understood it... I thought node was a single threaded, single process? Sure you can load balance across a number of processes, but that's not what he is claiming.

Thanks,
Ant

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The article your linking is incorrect and has been removed by IBM.

Node.js is single threaded and runs in one process because JavaScript is single threaded.

[Feel free to read Marak's critique of said article](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/ibm-doesnt-care-about-nodejs-people)